# Why did we get the MRNA-Vaccines for COVID before the "traditional" vaccines with inactivated coronavirus-components?

Tags: vaccine

i was wondering what the reasons, were, why got the MRNA-Vaccine faster, than the "traditionally" produced vaccines with inactivated viruscomponents.

What were there reasons behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chance, mostly.

[Pfizer's mRNA vaccine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfizer%E2%80%93BioNTech_COVID-19_vaccine#Clinical_trials) and [Sinovac's inactivated-virus vaccine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoronaVac#Phase_III) both started phase III trials in July of 2020.  The usual procedure for a phase III trial is to give a bunch of people either the vaccine or a placebo, and once a certain number of cases appear in the study group, check to see how many of those were in vaccinated individuals.

Pfizer's phase III trial took place in the United States, which saw a late-fall surge in the number of COVID-19 cases.  Sinovac's trial took place in Brazil, Chile, Indonesia, and Turkey, all of which saw steady or declining case counts over the same period.  As a result, Pfizer was able to get effectiveness data before Sinovac did.

(Other inactivated-virus vaccines either started trials later, or also picked trial sites that didn't see a fall surge in cases.)

Comment: Good answer - you could improve it by adding something about how long it takes to grow viruses such as these under GMP conditions. Flu vaccine is a good starting point for data on this.